# SQL results from two tables AND inner join on another?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables, `customer_special` and `customer_nuk` both contain the same columns exactly.

I have another table, `customer_data` indexed by `id`

I wish to run a query where the results contain all entries from `customer_special` and `customer_nuk` yet, using the value from the column `customer_special.user_id` and `customer_nuk.user_id` to `inner join` the results from `customer_data`.

Simply returning the `id` from `customer_data` with each row of `customer_special` and `customer_nuk` respectively would be great for this example. I have tried various things, none of which were what I was hoping for.

The following works as expected; inner joining the `customer_data` to the correct row from `customer_special` however it does not reference the two tables as requested.

```
SELECT
 t.order_id as "Order ID", t.BY1 as "By", t.order_type as "Type", t.O_DATE as "Order Date", 
 tr.short_name as "Customer short name", tr.www as "Customer website",
 tr.owner as "Customer owner", tr.postcode as "Customer postcode"
FROM customer_special t
INNER JOIN customer_data AS tr 
ON t.customer = tr.id
LIMIT 50
```

Then:

```
SELECT
 t.order_id as "Order ID", t.BY1 as "By", t.O_DATE as "Order Date",
 tr.short_name as "Customer short name", tr.www as "Customer website", 
 tr.owner as "Customer owner", tr.postcode as "Customer postcode"
FROM customer_special t
JOIN customer_nuk
INNER JOIN customer_data AS tr 
ON t.customer = tr.id
LIMIT 50
```

was my latest attempt.

Any help on what should be a simple task would be appreciated. Thank-you.

Comment: If the first works, please clarify what your question is.

Comment: It works as expected, but when i try to join the two tables as shown in the second code snippet, it does not work. The question is how can I do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what output you want? It's not clear to me if you want the two first tables joined and shown side by side, or if they should be treated as one table in the output.

Comment: @jpw your answer was perfect, thankyou. `select order_id, BY1, order_type, O_DATE, customer, short_name, www, owner, postcode from (
  select order_id, BY1, order_type, O_DATE, customer from customer_special
  union all
  select order_id, BY1, order_type, O_DATE, customer from customer_nuk
) src
join customer_data on src.customer = customer_data.id` worked exactly as needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all data from the two identical tables joined with the third, maybe what you're looking for is `union` which would make one set of the data from the two identical tables and join that set with the third table:

```
select * from (
  select * from customer_special
  union all
  select * from customer_nuk
) src
join customer_data on src.user_id = customer_data.id
```

Note that using `union all` won't eliminate any duplicate rows.

The `*` should be replaced by the columns you need from each table, and they have to be the same for both tables in the union.